# Matlab parsing at run-time of function handles

Tags: matlab, runtime, function-handle

**My Question:** Given a function handle, does matlab parse the string each time it needs to evaluate it, or just once and then it caches it?

**Example**

Consider the ingenious function

```
function [] = foo(func)
for j=1:1e4
    func(j);
end
```

and the script

```
func1 = @(x) 5*abs(x)^2
function foo(func1);
```

At run-time, Matlab needs to interpret `@(x) 5*abs(x)^2` as a function. In this example, does it do it once, or a thousand times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all `@(x)cos(x)` is not a string, it is an [anonymous function declaration](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). When you create an anonymous function, MATLAB essentially creates a function object which contains all of the information it needs to run. This anonymous function can then be passed around to various functions or even saved to a file. As such, it is only constructed once and evaluated many times.

When evaluated, MATLAB does not do any caching, so calling the same anonymous function with the same inputs many times causes the contents of the anonymous function to be evaluated each time.

If you want to get more information about your anonymous function, including the local workspace of the function, you can use the [`functions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html) function

```
f = @(x)cos(x);

functions(f)

%            function: '@(x)cos(x)'
%                type: 'anonymous'
%                file: ''
%           workspace: {[1x1 struct]}
%    within_file_path: '__base_function'
```

That being said, in your example, it could *really* be reduced to a [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) rather than an anonymous function since you pass all input arguments directly to `cos` without modifying them. As you can see, this has a different internal representation and from some preliminary benchmarks, it seems to be marginally faster.

```
f = @cos

functions(f)

%    function: 'cos'
%        type: 'simple'
%        file: ''
```

And a quick benchmark

```
function benchit
    fprintf('Anonymous function: %0.4f\n', timeit(@option1));
    fprintf('Function handle:    %0.4f\n', timeit(@option2));
end

function option2()
    f = @(x)cos(x);
    for k = 1:10000
        f(k);
    end
end

function option1()
    f = @cos;
    for k = 1:10000
        f(k);
    end
end
```

And the results (not really a huge difference)

```
Anonymous function: 0.0056
Function handle:    0.0049
```

**A few more things**

- When creating the anonymous function, the anonymous function declaration must still adhere to all of MATLAB's standard syntax rules otherwise it won't be created. For example, the following would throw an error during anonymous function *creation* since it is invalid syntax

  ```
  func = @(x)thing]
  ```

  > Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
- When you *evaluate* an anonymous function (after it's successful creation), it's just like evaluating any other function in that the anonymous function can throw an error and the error depends upon the input.

  ```
  func = @(x) x + [1 2];

  func([3 4])
  %   4   6

  % Now we're going to pass an array that isn't 1 x 2
  func([5 6 7])
  ```

  > Matrix dimensions must agree.
  >   Error in @(x)x+[1,2]

Comment: `functions` is documented: [https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html) – it is however only recommended for debugging.

Comment: @horchler Welp, not sure why I was thinking that. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: @Suever thanks. Couple of follow ups. (a)  I see why cosine is a bad example, I'll give one that really requires anonymous function. (b) A lot of times an anonymous function is created, but only when you try to evaluate or execute it, it throws an exception that this is not valid. Try to define `func2 = (x) dfadf9x)`. So, what kind of function does it store for `func2`?

Comment: @AmirSagiv Whether it's a function handle or an anonymous function, it doesn't matter. It's still created once and evaluated many times. An *error* when evaluating it is in the *evaluating part* of the above statement so an error can occur each time you evaluate it.

Comment: @AmirSagiv Also `func2 = (x)dfadf9x)` doesn't define *anything* because it's not a valid anonymous function definition and it will fail due to a syntax error.

Comment: @Suever of course it's not valid. My point is that when I define an anonymous function, it doesn't check that my definition bears any meaning or sense. It only checks what I've written in the evaluation side.

Comment: @AmirSagiv See my updates above. As far as errors, issues, etc. it's literally no different from a function file (the "correctness" isn't known until it's passed variables), it's just that it's defined inline.

Comment: @AmirSagiv I'm not sure what you're confused about. As I've restated many times. It's *created* once and *evaluated* many times. Each evaluation can throw it's own errors because it's evaluated with *whatever inputs you pass it that particular time*. I'm not sure how you would expect it to behave any different.

Comment: Yes, I see now in your response. It makes total sense, thanks.

Comment: @AmirSagiv if this answered your question consider marking it as a solution

Comment: @Suever , I still have a problem with run-times. In my codes it seems that using a function is much more slow then hard-coding this function into the code. Is this because it's a function (anonymous or not)?

Comment: @AmirSagiv Did you benchmark it by writing the function in a `.m` file and comparing? There is overhead when calling a function (anonymous or otherwise) as opposed to writing it directly into your code.

Comment: Ok, finally I've found the performance issue, which had nothing to do with the anonymous function mechanism. Still, I learnt a lot. Thanks!